# How to enable a package in yocto?

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I am new to `yocto` and I was using `openWRT` earlier. I want to enable `dropbear` with the `core-image-minimal`. How to do this?

I have `dropbear` bb file in `sources/poky/meta/recipies-core/dropbear` and `sources/poky/meta/recipes-core/packagegroups`.

I tried appending the `packagegroup-core-ssh-dropbear.bb` to the `IMAGE_INSTALL` in `sources/poky/meta/recepies-core/image/core-image-minimal.bb` and this throws error `Nothing provides dropbear`.

How to enable this?. Don't we have a `menuconfig` or equivalent to enable a package/recipe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add the following

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = "dropbear"
```

to  your image recipe